# jQuery hover (show-hide)

Tags: jquery, hover, hide, show

I work on popup menu in jQuery with show/hide. I want to make a green rectangle for my example clikable too.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5cRU/27/

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('.rectangle1').hide();

$('#rectangle').hover(function() {
    $('.rectangle1').show()
   },function() {
  $('.rectangle1').hide()
   });  
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an area for `.rectangle1` inside:

```
<div class="rectangle1">
    <div class="rectangle1-area"></div>
</div>
```

Add a top padding to this area. So your areas will be gapless.
Also you can add a **display: none;** to `.rectangle1` instead of hiding it in JavaScript.

```
.rectangle1 {
    width: 140px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: none;
}
.rectangle1-area {   
   width: 100%; 
   height: 150px;
   background: #37CA90;
}
```

Use a count variable. So if your mouse is over `#rectangle` or `.rectangle1` the **var is 1**.
If mouseout - the **var is 0** => hide `.rectangle1`

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var count = 0;
    $('#rectangle, .rectangle1').mouseenter(function() {
        count++;
        $('.rectangle1').show();
    });
    
    $('#rectangle, .rectangle1').mouseleave(function() {
        count--;
        if (count == 0) { 
            $('.rectangle1').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this by toggling it in the first function and doing nothing in the second function. It is important to not leave the second function, since if it is left, the first function will take place of it, and we come to the start of the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.rectangle1').hide();
    $('#rectangle').hover(function () {
        $('.rectangle1').toggle();
    }, function () {
       // leave it empty
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5cRU/28/)

Comment: remove the function if it needs to leave empty.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal no. Then the first function will take place of it

Comment: it is doesn't work like i want. I want only when  mouse hover on blue, the green visiable is and when mouseover on green the green clickable is.

Comment: @user123456 that's what's happening

Comment: i want to make something like this,but without fadeIn/Out , because of opacity. http://jsfiddle.net/4Uk5P/23/

Comment: @user123456 check the demo now

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to click your popup, because as soon as you mouse is not hovering on the blue rectangle, the other rectangle disappears.

To make it possible, you will have to make the two rectangles right next to each other, and make the second rectangle also display when you are hovering over it, or hide/hover on click of the first rectangle. Then you can make something happen on click using

```
$("#ID_OF_RECTANGLE_TWO").click(function(){DO_SOMETHING_HERE;});
```