# jQuery Show/Hide on Hover // Show on Click

Tags: jquery, html, hover, click, hide

I have a question related to this one:

[jQuery hover (show-hide)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403146/jquery-hover-show-hide)

However, in his fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5cRU/27/

He has two divs

```
<div id="rectangle"></div>
<div class="rectangle1"></div>
```

They are similar, but different colored

```
      rectangle {
      width: 140px; 
      height: 80px;
      background: #037CA9;
      margin-bottom:10px;
}

      .rectangle1 {
      width: 140px; 
      height: 150px;
      background: #37CA90;
}
```

How would he be able to click the dark blue rectangle to make the light blue rectangle stay?

If you load the fiddle, all the code is there.

Comment: `rectangle` is looking for element of *type* `<rectangle>`, which you don't have, so the selector won't match any element.

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/Q5cRU/33/) what you want???

Comment: well, I'm using his setup as my own just until I figure out how to code this right. If I have the same code as his, the two rectangles and all, but I just want to keep the light green rectangle visible upon clicking the dark blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a state flag which toggles if the rectangle is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var clicked=false;

  $('.rectangle1').hide();

    $('#rectangle').on('click', function() {
        clicked = !clicked;
    });

    $('#rectangle').hover(
      function() {
        $('.rectangle1').show()}
      ,function() {
          if (!clicked) {
             $('.rectangle1').hide()
          }
      }
    );  
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5cRU/34/

Similarly, clicking it again allows the bottom rectangle to hide.

Comment: that's exactly what i needed. and what do you mean by the state flag? not the best with this stuff.

Comment: Its just a simple boolean which remembers the 'state' of whether the user has clicked yet, or not. We toggle it on a click.

Answer (score 0):

replace the javascript code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rectangle1').hide();

  $('#rectangle').click(function() {
 $('.rectangle1').show()
  });
});
```

Comment: I need the original to work as well. I just want to be able to click the dark blue and make the green rectangle stay.

Comment: if you want when you click on the dark blue , The Light One Show And Stay , Replace your JQuery With This Code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rectangle1').hide();

  $('#rectangle').hover(function() {
 $('.rectangle1').show()
  },function() {
      $('.rectangle1').hide()
  });  
});
```

In this code, it is clear that on hovering rectangle with id is equal to rectangle, rectangle1 is shown to us. It is simple jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the class and add a similar one containing the same css properties, that way hover wont trigger after it has been clicked. 
here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5cRU/37/).

```
$('#rectangle').click(function(){
    $('.rectangle1').addClass('rectangle2');
    $('.rectangle1').removeClass('rectangle1');
});
```

CSS

```
.rectangle1, .rectangle2  {
   width: 140px; 
   height: 150px;
   background: #37CA90;
}
```

EDIT: Code optimized, fiddleJS link updated.