# Jquery hover - keep popup open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well, I am trying to make a button which, when a user hovers on it, will display a container which has text in it. And I am wondering if it is possible to have the container which pops up stays open if you hover down to it.

It is similar to [this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403146/jquery-hover-show-hide)

However the answer on that thread does not help me, as it does not solve the issue.

My code:

HTML:

```
<a href="#contact">
    <div class="button">
       <div class="button-text contactme">
            Contact me
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
<div class="emailcontainer">
    contact@website.com
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.emailcontainer {
    display:none;
    color:#fff;
    border:solid 1px #fff;
    padding:10px;
    padding-left:50px;
    padding-right:50px
}

.button-text {
    padding:0 25px;
    line-height:56px;
    letter-spacing:3px
}

.button-text.contactme {
    font-weight:20px
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button-text.contactme").hover(function() {
    $('.emailcontainer').show('slow')
},function() {
    $('.emailcontainer').hide('slow')
    });  
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hover down to it"? Do you want to open the popup when you hover over the button and keep it open when you hover away from the button? If so, how do you want to close the popup?

Comment: @newmediafreak I mean, if I was to move the mouse down and hover over the popup container, it will still show, not hide as it currently does.

Comment: How about moving the `.emailcontainer` inside your button div? https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/yqj7zjjp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7f3f3dp5/)

Update your jQuery code as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".button-text.contactme, .emailcontainer").hover(function() {
    $('.emailcontainer').show('slow')
},function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
        if(!($('.emailcontainer:hover').length > 0))
            $('.emailcontainer').hide('slow');
        }, 300);
    });  
});
```

Hope this help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why you are trying to reinvent the wheel, have a look Qtip with verity of feature:

http://qtip2.com/demos

Answer (score 0):

I your emailcontainer class in CSS, remove the `color:#fff;`, because it is white. Or you can change the color which is not white
see fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tn5wy5dk/1/

Comment: And also observe that I have removed 'display:none;' from CSS and added this style to the DIV tag in HTML

Comment: How is this an answer to the question? Also, why should the OP be doing that? There probably is a dark background, so that you can see the white bordered popup with white text in it.

Answer (score 0):

you may use mouseover and mouseout
https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/
If you do not have a cross/close button on the popup then you can use mouseout for hiding the popup

Answer (score 0):

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/yqj7zjjp/2/)

1. You can move the `.emailcontainer` inside your button div so it'll
   share the hover even nothing extra needed:

   ```
   <div class="button-text contactme">
       Contact me
       <div class="emailcontainer">contact@website.com</div>
   </div>
   ```
2. If you want it to be popup, you need to set the container to have
   `position: relative` and the popup to have `position: absolute;`:

   ```
   .button-text.contactme {
       position: relative;
   }
   .emailcontainer {
       position: absolute;
       top: 40px;
       left: 20px;
       /* the rest of styles */
   }
   ```
3. I don't think `50px` is a proper value for `font-weight`. You either
   meant to use `font-size: 50px;` or something like `font-weight: bold;`.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML CODE**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="app2.js"></script>

<style>
.emailcontainer {
    display:none;
    color:blue;
    border:solid 1px black;
    padding:10px;
    padding-left:50px;
    padding-right:50px
}

.button-text {
    padding:0 25px;
    line-height:56px;
    letter-spacing:3px
}

.button-text.contactme {
    font-weight:20px
}

</style>
</head>

<body> 
  <a href="#contact">
      <div class="button">
         <div class="button-text contactme">
              Contact me
          </div>
      </div>
  </a>
  <br/>
  <div id="emailcontainerdiv" class="emailcontainer">
      contact@website.com
  </div> 




</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".button-text.contactme").hover(function() {
         $('#emailcontainerdiv').show();
       },function() {
     $('#emailcontainerdiv').show();
     });  
 });
```